# Android, how to show status-bar temporarily WITHOUT resizing whole window?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Thanks for open this thread, I want to achieve this effect in **my reader app** but having no idea:

[image: Effect sample]

When in reading mode, it shows full-screen text. Once I click on the screen, it **keeps showing** the status-bar and toolbar, unless I scroll or click again on the screen.

As you can see in the image below, the texts are always in the same position, and the toolbar is floating on the texts layout.

I want some hints on achieving this effects:

> Click on the screen to show the status-bar, and keep showing; click again to dismiss it.
>
> Clicking events and scrolling events are still available to the texts when the actionbar layout showing. And the texts layout does not resize because of the showing of status-bar.

Thank you very much!!